# When is a graded ring the cohomology ring of a CW-complex?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $A^*$ be a graded-commutative ring with $A^n = 0$ for sufficiently large $n$ and each $A^n$ finitely generated. When does there exist a finite CW-complex $X$ with $H^*(X) \cong A$ as graded rings?

Comment: IIRC the answer is quite delicate due to the presence of cohomology operations. For example (http://mathoverflow.net/a/6673/290) it's known that if $\mathbb{Z}[x]/x^4$ appears as a cohomology ring then $x$ must have degree $2$ or $4$. In particular there cannot exist a space that deserves to be called $\mathbb{OP}^3$.

Comment: It would also be good to specify coefficients (for $A$ and for your cohomology) here.

Comment: I'm working over $\mathbb{Z}$ throughout, for simplicity.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I had a run across a few scattered results that certain rings couldn't be of the form $H^*(X)$ for "reasonable" $X$, but they seemed mostly ad hoc. It makes sense that the obstruction would be related to cohomology operations, but I'm not sure how to formalize that. Relatedly, if some $K(\pi, n)$ is finite-dimensional (which probably won't be too useful for $\pi = \mathbb{Z}$, but may be useful for, say, fundamental groups of closed hyperbolic manifolds), then we get a relation like $\alpha^p = 0$, independent of $X$. But I don't know how to proceed more systematically.